# Deciphering puppet output

Tags: puppet

I am very new to puppet and just trying to understand what the output is telling me.  I have a very simple init.pp file for configuring the shudders file:

```
class sudo {
    package { sudo:
                    ensure => present,
                    }

    if $operatingsystem == "Ubuntu" {
            package { "sudo-ldap":
                                ensure => present,
                                require => Package["sudo"],
                            }
            }
    file { "/etc/sudoers":
                    owner => "root",
                    group => "wheel",
                    mode => 0440,
                    source => "puppet:///modules/sudo/sudoers",
                    require => Package["sudo"],
                }
```

However whenever I run the following command:

```
sudo puppet agent --server=my-imac.local --no-daemonize --verbose --onetime --noop
```

I get the following output:

```
info: Caching catalog for susan-hirschs-imac.local
info: Applying configuration version '1321294018'
notice: /Stage[main]/Sudo/Package[sudo]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
notice: Class[Sudo]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
notice: Stage[main]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.07 seconds
```

I have 2 questions:

1) how do I interpret this path:  `/Stage[main]/Sudo/Package[sudo]/ensure`

2) Why is it telling me the current value is absent?  I have a sudoers file at /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The paths are generated from the location of the resource (where a resource is a file, package, service etc).  In your case:

   - `Stage[main]` is the default "stage" for this resource.  [Stages](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#run-stages) let you separate resources into chunks, so everything in stage A is carried out before stage B (e.g. repository config before installing packages etc).  The "main" stage is the default.
   - `Sudo` is the name of the class containing your resources.
   - `Package[sudo]` is the full name of one of your resources.  The type, `Package`, is always capitalised when referred to like this.  The `sudo` is the name, or title.  Sometimes the title doesn't match the real location of the resource (e.g. you could have file "foo" actually at "/foo/bar").
   - `ensure` is the property or attribute of the resource.  Puppet works by inspecting each property on a resource and using a provider (OS-specific code) to change it from the current value (e.g. "absent") to the one in the manifest ("present").

   The path can get more complicated when you nest language structures, such as defines - but it all follows the same pattern.
2. Puppet is looking for a package exactly named `sudo`.  It might be that you have an /etc/sudoers file, but the package isn't named sudo.

   Try running `puppet resource package` to see what packages Puppet can see on your OS (you didn't mention it).  You can add `--debug` and it will also show the commands Puppet is running to get the information, which might help you work out which package manager it has found.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That was an excellent response!  Much more thorough than in any of the documents I've found.  Just out of curiosity, where did you get your puppet knowledge from?

Comment: Glad it helped.  Self-taught mostly, though a few years ago now.  For starting, I'd suggest the [Learning Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/) tutorial which is new, but explains some useful concepts.  There are also two quite new books, Pro Puppet and Puppet Cookbook which are both supposed to be good.